Determine $\overline{ab}$ by $\overline{abab}+\sqrt{2-\overline{ab}+\sqrt{(\overline{ab}+1)(\overline{ab}^3-3\overline{ab}^2+2\overline{ab})+1}}=2039$
the problem
Determine the natural number of the form $\overline{ab}$, written in base $10$, for which $\overline{abab}+\sqrt{2-\overline{ab}+\sqrt{(\overline{ab}+1)(\overline{ab}^3-3*\overline{ab}^2+2*\overline{ab})+1}}=2039$
my idea
its clear that $\sqrt{2-\overline{ab}+\sqrt{(\overline{ab}+1)(\overline{ab}^3-3*\overline{ab}^2+2*\overline{ab})+1}}$ should be natural so $2-\overline{ab}+\sqrt{(\overline{ab}+1)(\overline{ab}^3-3*\overline{ab}^2+2*\overline{ab})+1}$ is a perfect square of a natural number
then its a=again clear that $\sqrt{(\overline{ab}+1)(\overline{ab}^3-3*\overline{ab}^2+2*\overline{ab})+1}$ its natural so $(\overline{ab}+1)(\overline{ab}^3-3*\overline{ab}^2+2*\overline{ab})+1$ its a perfect square of a natural number
Now i noted $\overline{ab}=x$ and i got to $(x+1)(x^3-3x^2+2x)+1=(x^2+x-1)(x^2-x-1)$ which is a perfect square
From here i got stuck and didnt knew what to do.
By brute force i found out that the answer is 14, if is going to help.
Hope one of youcan help me! Thank you!

@user170231 actually a can be 2 and b=0

$$(x^2+x-1)(x^2-x-1) = (x^2-1)^2-x^2 = a^2$$, so it's a Pythagorean triple which you can parametrize. Not sure if this will make it too much faster.

For $x=\overline{ab}$ a two-digits integer number solution to the given equation we have first $10\le x\le 20$.
Now under the inner most square we have
$$(x-2)(x+1)\cdot (x-1)x+1=(x^2-x-2)(x^2-x)+1=\Big((x^2-x-1)-1\Big)\Big((x^2-x-1)+1\Big)+1=(x^2-x-1)^2\ .
$$
For our $x$ (between ten and twenty) this inner square root is thus $x^2-x-1>0$.
To this result we add $2-x$, thus get $2-x+(x^2-x-1)=(x-1)^2$.
We can extract the square root, which is for our $x$ then $(x-1)>0$.
It turns out that $x=20$ is the wanted solution.
To recap and complete, we bring then our equation to the simplest form.
Note that $\overline{abab}=100\overline{ab}+\overline{ab}=100x+x=101x$. So we write successively:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2039 &=
101x+\sqrt{2-x+\sqrt{(x-1)(x-2)x(x+1)+1}}\ ,\\
2039 &=
101x + \sqrt{2-x+(x^2-x-1)}\ ,\\
2039 &=
101x + (x-1)\ ,\\
2040&=102x\ ,\\
20&=x\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Denoting $\overline{ab}=x$ we have the equation
$$101x+\sqrt{2-x+\sqrt{x(x+1)(x-1)(x-2)+1}}=2039\\101x+\sqrt{2-x+\sqrt{(x^2-x-1)^2}}=2039$$ so the two equations
$$101x+\sqrt{2-x+(x^2-x-1)}=2039\\101x+\sqrt{2-x-(x^2-x-1)}=2039$$ Only the first leads to a solution, in fact we have $$101x+\sqrt{(x-1)^2}=2039\Rightarrow\begin{cases}101x+(x-1)=2039\Rightarrow \boxed{x=20}\\101x-(x-1)=2039\end{cases}$$ where again only the first give the solution $x=20$.
